# Segmentation fault when using OpenMP for_each and BOOST_FOREACH

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, openmp, boost-bind

I searched a lot on a parallelized version of `for_each` in C++. I found the following piece of code regarding paralleling `for_each` from [here](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=109):

```
template<class T, class Function>
void parallel_for_each(std::vector< T> & obj, Function f)
{
  int size = obj.size();
  #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(f) shared(obj)
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    f(obj[i]);
  }
}
```

Here is a piece of my code:

```
class A;
typedef std::vector <A> vec_A;
typedef std::vector <vec_A> vec_2D_A;
vec_2D_A a2d; 
...
//serial
BOOST_FOREACH(vec_A& av, a2d)
{
  for_each(av.begin(), av.end(), boost::bind(detect_Type, _1, CGAL, *this));
}
// parallel (segfault here!)
BOOST_FOREACH(vec_A& av, a2d)
{
  parallel_for_each(av, boost::bind(detect_Type, _1, ALL, *this));
}
...
```

Class `A` is a class of a specific point. Each member has a variable corresponding to its coordinates and couple of other member variables.
The function `detect_type` is modifying members of `av`.

All members inside `vec_pnt` are independent from each other, but I still receive a segfault.

**EDIT**:

here is more section of code. detect_type is responsible to find the type of the each object of A using Nearest Neighbor search and help of the XfieldPlus class itself.

```
void detect_Type(A& PNT, const NNSerach NNType, const xFieldPlus& lst)
{
  switch (NNType)
  {
    case 0: 
    {
      Nvertex = ANN_nearest(tip, lst); // It is NOT thread safe.
    }
      break;
    case 1:
    {
      Nvertex = BOOST_nearest(tip, lst);
    }
      break;
    case 2:  //we use CGAL
    {
      Nvertex = CGAL_nearest(tip, lst);
    }
      break; 
    default:
      std::cout << "Unknown NN-Serach" << std::endl;
      break;
  }
  ....
  for(Entity::edgeIterator edgIter = f.beginEdge(); edgIter!= f.endEdge(); ++edgIter)
       {
         mesh::Edge edg = *edgIter;
         if (edg != ed)
         {
           if (lst.getVal(edg.vertex(0)) * lst.getVal(edg.vertex(1)) < 0.0 )
           {
             PNT._type = ON_EDGE_NEED;
             return;
           }
         }
       }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run it with Valgrind to check for memory issues? [Here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html#drd-manual.openmp) is a link on how to debug OpenMP with Valgrind.

Comment: Not really, first I want to make sure if the code is correct itself.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. In particular, `detect_Type` and the class indicated by `*this`. That should all be thread safe. My guess it: it's not thread safe.

Comment: @sehe I edited the question. I hope it is more clear now.